Sending a struct with an array as an SSBO
I am working on a voxel engine in OpenGL and want a way to send my chunks to my shader
I know there are some really efficient methods and data structures out there to send voxels such as Sparse Voxel Octrees but I want to start simple, with only one chunk.
In c++ chunk is defined as:
struct Chunk {
    alignas(4) int voxelNum;
    alignas(4) float voxelSize;
    alignas(4) float chunkSize;
    alignas(16) glm::vec4 position;
    bool grid[16 * 16];
};

The SSBO is like this in glsl:
struct Chunk {
    int voxelNum;
    float voxelSize;
    float chunkSize;
    vec4 position;
    bool grid[16 * 16];
};

layout (std140)  uniform ChunkData {
    Chunk chunk;
};

And the data is sent like this:
GLuint buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(Chunk), &chunk, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

I tested the code and this works great for all the variables up to the  grid[]  array. There, only the first element is correct.
How should I tackle this? More specifically, how can I send a single struct like this from my c++ code to the shader?

make bool an int. I assume bool is 8 bit on your CPU side, while it's 32 on the GPU side.

This question is similar to: std140 and bool alignment. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
